# Error during debugging Android application using Nvidia Debug Manager for Android NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I try to debug C++ code in application "hello-jni" from ndk samples using eclipse.
I installed Tegra Android Development Pack.
The application is working if I use Run As Android Application.

I tried to debug using configuration named "Android NKD Application"(from Tegra Android Development Pack). 
After beginning debug I receives error: **"An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration".
com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getValidAvds()[Lcom/android/sdklib/internal/avd/AvdManager$AvdInfo;"**

Does anyone knows how to fix that? Thanks

Comment: The reason was "The Tegra Android Development Pack install the latest ADT for you during installation process, the latest update in ADT 12.0.0 broke our gdb integration. "

Comment: That's great that you figured this out. The usual practice is to post your findings as an answer and mark it as Accepted. That way other people can learn from your question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions